# How can I name controllers with have more than one word in Kohana 3?

Tags: kohana

If I want a `home` controller in Kohana, I can do that relatively simple.

#### APPPATH/classes/controller/home.php

```
class Controller_Home extends Controller_Base { ... }
```

But what if I want one that is called refer_a_friend?

I can't do this because Kohana sees an underscore as a directory separator.

#### APPPATH/classes/controller/refer_a_friend.php

```
class Controller_Refer_A_Friend extends Controller_Base { ... }
```

What can I do?

Answer (score 8):

[The official guide](http://kohanaframework.org/guide/about.conventions#classes) says you can use camelCase to avoid the `_` -> `DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR` mapping.

This is the only time where camelCase should be used in Kohana.

Answer (score 7):

1.Using subdirectories:

**APPPATH/classes/controller/refer/a/friend.php**

```
class Controller_Refer_A_Friend
extends Controller_Base { ... }
```

2.Using routes:

**APPPATH/bootstrap.php**

```
Route::add('controller_with_underscores',
'refer_a_friend(/<action>(/<id>))')
    ->defaults(array(
        'controller'  => 'referafriend', ));
```

Comment: Or just call your controller "referrals", it doesn't have to match the URL at all.